# Twitter OEmbed URL "No-Access-Control-Allow-Origin" from a regular server

Tags: ajax, angularjs, http, twitter

I'm getting the following error when I try to get a Tweet's html based on an ID:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?id=484587947543781376. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://app-theysoundlike.rhcloud.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

As you can see, the origin is not `localhost`, it is on a regular server on Openshift. I'm using the following AngularJS code to make the request:

```
$http({
        url:'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?id='+data.id,
        method:"GET"
        }).success(function(data){
            $scope.tweetHTML = data.html;
            $scope.tweetAvailable = true;
        });
});
```

The `data.id` thing is not a problem, because the URL is being formed properly. The actual request is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use $http.jsonp with url

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?id={{YOUR_ID}}&callback=JSON_CALLBACK
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I have a question though. Do I put the function name in the `JSON_CALLBACK` parameter. Also.. how does that work? How will twitter call a function on my site?

Comment: JSON_CALLBACK need for standart angularjs $http callback - function JSON_CALLBACK automatically sends to $http.jsonp().success() or .fail().  I don't go deep to this technology, maybe this article can help with it - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: @strlok2010, thanks, learned something new today. So just to clarify, JSON_CALLBACK is not a placeholder for my own function, but rather something that Angular references?